# WCF - More than one endpoint configuration for that contract was found - Error

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis-7.5

We have working ASP.Net web application with WCF. wcf service hosted as a windows service. All is fine. Then we made a change so that service contract will have different namespace (From Namespace1.IserviceContract to Namespace2.IserviceContract). After the change we deployed to the server and getting following error when we try to instantiate the service object.

```
    System.InvalidOperationException: An endpoint configuration section for contract 'Namespace2.IserviceContract' could not be loaded because more than one endpoint configuration for that contract was found. Please indicate the preferred endpoint configuration section by name.

Generated: Fri, 06 Jul 2012 21:02:56 GMT


System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: An endpoint configuration section for contract 'Namespace2.IserviceContract' could not be loaded because more than one endpoint configuration for that contract was found. Please indicate the preferred endpoint configuration section by name.
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LookupChannel(String configurationName, String contractName, Boolean wildcard)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadChannelBehaviors(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, String configurationName)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration(String configurationName, Configuration configuration)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration(String configurationName)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint(String configurationName, EndpointAddress address)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(String endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
   at System.ServiceModel.EndpointTrait`1.CreateSimplexFactory()
   at System.ServiceModel.EndpointTrait`1.CreateChannelFactory()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelFactoryRef(EndpointTrait`1 endpointTrait)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.InitializeChannelFactoryRef()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1..ctor()
   at TestApplication.ManagementWrapper.VerifyAuthentication(Int32 appId, String Token)
   at TestApplication.VerifyAuthentication(String tokenstring)
```

we did a research about this issue and found that this type if exception shows up if we have two client endpoints defined in our web.config file. however we are certain that we have only one client endpoint defined. More over this exception shows up only in the server. local works fine. here is our service model:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_Management" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="4194304" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="32768" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://servername:9010/Management/service/ManagementService" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_Management" contract="Namespace2.IserviceContract" name="NetTcpBinding_IserviceContract" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

we also tried to restart IIS and application pool. Still getting the same exception.

Comment: I just want to comment that WCF is the biggest configuration hassle since anything hard to configure.

Comment: Is there an endpoint added through code?

Comment: @Lieven: No, there is no endpoint added through code.

Comment: This may help someone in the future - even if you have just one endpoint, you may need to refer to it by name in your code.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try searching your web.config for another  that is using the web address as your ManagementService.  Also, search the web.config for any reference to the old namespace (contract="Namespace1.IserviceContract").  Don't forget to check for extra .config files.  That little gotcha has burned me before.

Answer (score 3):

Whatever protocol is being called like basic, net.tcp or wshttp, that address should be in web config file remove other addresses from **client** section in app.config file, in my case i  am calling the service as **htp://machinename:700/test.svc** but in the client section there were addresses with net.tcp and wshttp configurations, removed those addresses and issue is fixed for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please right click on svc file of your wcf service and click on View markup.

then modify namespace there also. It should work fine then.

Comment: Your confirguration should look like this                    <service name="NameSpace.YourService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="binaryHttp"
          contract="NameSpace.IYourService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>

Answer (score 0):

If everything in your web.config appears to be correct, this error can be caused by another application on the same server. I spent several days troubleshooting a similar issue.

In my case, the environment had a large number of WCF services deployed as web applications in IIS under a single website as follows.

```
/Root Website
    /Service1
    /Service2
    /Service3
    /ServiceX
```

One of the child services was mistakenly deployed to the root website physical folder rather than to it's own physical folder. This bad deployment contained a client endpoint definition that was common to all of the services and caused all of the child services to break. Apparently, the same client endpoint cannot be used by the parent website and a child web application.

Removing the client endpoint from the root website fixed the issue for me.